# Adding an MXML component as a child of the main application using ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

How can I add an MXML component as a child of the main application using ActionScript. It's not possible to instatiate it, is it? Assuming that behind every mxml file stands an actionscrpt3 class, I tried to import it but id didn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to familiarize yourself with the flex component lifecycle: http://msimtiyaz.wordpress.com/flex/adobe-flex-component-instantiation-life-cycle/

It explains the actionscript code behind the mxml components, and it's important to be familiar with, because if you implement your components incorrectly, it can really slow down your application.

Anyway, I think you may be confused about what imports do. Import statements make the code available to use in your code, but it wouldn't create a component. You'd need to create a component the same way you create any object in actionscript, and then you'll need to add that component to the display list to make it show up.

The appropriate place to do this is in the createChildren() function:

```
override protected function createChildren():void {
    super.createChildren();

    var myText:Text = new Text();//create a new object
    this.addChild(myText);//add it to the display list
}
```